# What is the idiomatic way to have a private function tested?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, idioms

The Rust book [says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/testing.html#the-tests-module) that using a "tests" module is the idiomatic way to have unit tests. But I cannot see a function from the super module in the tests module if that function is not marked 'pub'. How should one test internal functions then?

My first instinct was to look for a way to `#ifdef` the keyword `pub`. I have done this in the past for C++ testing. For Rust what I have done is simply have tests for private functions in the module and then tests for the public interface in the "tests" module.

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nest your test module inside the module containing the private methods or structs:

```
mod inners {
    fn my_func() -> u8 { 42 }

    mod test {
        #[test]
        fn is_answer() {
            assert_eq!(42, super::my_func());
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I disagree that you should test private stuff in general, but thats a different discussion.

Comment: I had done this at first but I was doing `use super::*`. If I just explicitly `use super::some_function` it works as you describe. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanPerry AFAIK glob imports don't include functions, only types. One of the few times I use glob imports is when I am writing my test module, as I usually want to test everything in the parent module.

Comment: @Shepmaster wouldn't it be good practice to use `#[cfg(test)]` on `mod test`?

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way to test a private function is not to. Unit tests are supposed to test a class' public behavior. Private methods are just implementation details of the aforementioned public methods which you should test.

Comment: I have simple internals that do not log or print or anything. The public routines which call them do. So my unit tests are quiet, idempotent, etc. This is not testing external access which is often what is buried in the private regions of code.

Comment: @SeanPerry I would disagree that one is often testing external access. Indeed, having pure logic exposed as public functions or methods allows downstream consumers is even nicer. You can test that public interface and users of your library deal with the IO bits.

Comment: Sometimes you need to have access to implementation details to trigger a certain behaviour through the public API. A simple example would be testing an array sort method: At low amounts, ie. around 10 elements, using bubblesort instead of quicksort (or similar) is typically faster. The threshold is a private implementation detail, but you need to know it to reliably trigger both codepaths in your test.