# Conditional visibility for unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I'm building a crate for reading and writing a file format. Reading is accomplished via `nom` parser-combinators. As a result I have lots of small parser methods like:

```
named!(read_prop_fs<&[u8], PropChunk>, do_parse!(
    tag!("FS  ") >>
    size: be_u64 >>
    fs: be_u32   >>
    (PropChunk { id: PropId::FS(fs), size: size })
));
```

The parser functions are in `io::input::internal` and are all private. Most of the data types they use are also private to that module.

The file writer code I would like to test is in `io::output::internal`. Ideally, I would like to use the parser functions in unit tests for the writer.

Making all these methods and types `pub` or even `crate` seems very ugly. It seems equally strange to invert the modules, having the equivalent of `io::internal::{input, output}` where `input` and `output` are ultimately `pub` and represent the crate API.

Is there a way to do something like this?

> When `#[cfg(test)]` is true the default visibility in the current module should be `crate`, otherwise the default should be private.

If not, is there a typical, ergonomic workaround?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [What is the idiomatic way to have a private function tested?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31752882/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Otherwise, it's answered by the answers of [How do I change a function's qualifiers via conditional compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49479854/155423).

Comment: Yes, the conditional compilation macros are probably the closest to what I want.